# GraphViz in memory rendering appears on stdout

Tags: graphviz

I am calling GraphViz from Java via JNI to lay out graphs. When I call function gvRenderData from GraphViz's library gvc, which renders the graph layout into a malloc'ed atring (instead of doing file I/O), unfortunately I also see the rendered graph appear on the console. So in fact gvRenderData also seems to write to stdout. This is a real nuisance for graphs with thousands of nodes. I have tried passing args like `-o/dev/null` into the GraphViz context, but to no avail.

Does anyone know how to turn off that unwanted behavior? I use GraphViz 2.40.1 under Linux.

Here are the basics of my code. No surprises there. Native interfaces have been generated with SWIG.

```
SWIGTYPE_p_GVC_t gvCtx = gvc.gvContext();
String[] argv = {"dot", "-y", "-q"};
gvc.gvParseArgs(gvCtx, argv.length, argv);
SWIGTYPE_p_graph_t graph = cgraph.agmemread(dot);
gvc.gvLayout(gvCtx, graph, "dot");
String[] rendered = new String[1];
gvc.gvRenderData(gvCtx, graph, "json", rendered, new long[1]);
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to render the graph?

Comment: @Botje edited my question to show the code. I guess that won't help much, it's a totally unsurprising sequence of native method calls from Java.

Comment: Behind the scenes, `gvParseArgs` sets up a job that runs with default settings (ie output to stdout). If I comment that everything works as you expect. For inverting the Y axis you will need to declare an `extern int Y_invert;` and set it to 1.

Comment: @Botje thanks for finding this out. Indeed when I leave out the call to `gvParseArgs` the unwanted output disappears. However, as for your suggestion how to specify y-axis inversion without calling `gvParseArgs`, I must have misunderstood it. I did try putting the following in my SWIG interface file and calling `invertY` in my code, but it had no effect: `%{ extern int Y_invert; %} %inline %{ void invertY() { Y_invert = 1; } } %}`

Comment: That sounds like it should work ... From what I could gather the inversion logic is inherited from whatever renderer you use (`json` does not invert), the `Y_invert` variable, or the flags in the GVC job object. `gvRenderData` creates the job for you, so this `Y_invert` seems like the only viable approach. You should make a follow-up question if you cannot get it to work with the global variable.

Comment: Thanks. If you promote your comment to an answer, I would accept it.